# Java Stream convert Map with List values to one big list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> numbersMap = new HashMap<>();
numbersMap.put("A", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
numbersMap.put("B", Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
numbersMap.put("C", Arrays.asList(7,8, 9));
```

How do I get a `List` out of it?

```
List<Integer> allnumbers = //?
```

that contains `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use flatMap to merge each list's stream:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> numbersMap = new HashMap<>();
numbersMap.put("A", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
numbersMap.put("B", Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
numbersMap.put("C", Arrays.asList(7,8, 9));

List<Integer> output = numbersMap.values()
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(output);
```

And the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

You stream the values and use `flatMap()` to create one stream that is the  concatenation of the streams of each List:

```
List<Integer> allnumbers = numbersMap.values().stream()
   .flatMap(List::stream) // secret sauce
   .collect(toList());
```